# Efficiently combine min/max on different columns of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that contains the results of computation and need to:

- take the maximum value of a column and for that value find the maximum value of another column
- take the minimum value of a column and for that value find the maximum value of another column

Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Setup

```
metrictuple = namedtuple('metrics', 'prob m1 m2')
l1 =[metrictuple(0.1, 0.4, 0.04),metrictuple(0.2, 0.4, 0.04),metrictuple(0.4, 0.4, 0.1),metrictuple(0.7, 0.2, 0.3),metrictuple(1.0, 0.1, 0.5)]
df = pd.DataFrame(l1)
# df
#   prob   m1    m2
#0   0.1  0.4  0.04
#1   0.2  0.4  0.04
#2   0.4  0.4  0.10
#3   0.7  0.2  0.30
#4   1.0  0.1  0.50

tmp = df.loc[(df.m1.max() == df.m1), ['prob','m1']]
res1 = tmp.loc[tmp.prob.max() == tmp.prob, :].to_records(index=False)[0]
#(0.4, 0.4)
tmp = df.loc[(df.m2.min() == df.m2), ['prob','m2']]
res2 = tmp.loc[tmp.prob.max() == tmp.prob, :].to_records(index=False)[0]
#(0.2, 0.04)
```

Comment: did the below solution solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the solution and it works as expected. I have timed the code and can confirm its very efficient.

Comment: excellent, that's good to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas isn't ideal for numerical computations. This is because there is a significant overhead in slicing and selecting data, in this example `df.loc`.

The good news is that `pandas` interacts well with `numpy`, so you can easily drop down to the underlying `numpy` arrays.

Below I've defined some helper functions which makes the code more readable. Note that `numpy` slicing is performed via row and column numbers starting from 0.

```
arr = df.values

def arr_max(x, col):
    return x[x[:,col]==x[:,col].max()]

def arr_min(x, col):
    return x[x[:,col]==x[:,col].min()]

res1 = arr_max(arr_max(arr, 1), 0)[:,:2]     # array([[ 0.4,  0.4]])
res2 = arr_max(arr_min(arr, 2), 0)[:,[0,2]]  # array([[ 0.2 ,  0.04]])
```